# Selecting Specific value from table via sql

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to select a field within a table in a database called 'Noofdays'
To be used in a calculation later on. My problem is its value just remains 0.

Here is my code

```
    Private Sub GetRentalDays()
    'Select the rental record for the Current Rental with ID CurrentRentalID
    If DbConnect() Then
        Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
        With SQLCmd
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "Select Tbl_Rental.RentalID, Tbl_Rental.Noofdays from Tbl_Rental Where RentalID = @CurrentrentalID"
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RentalID", CurrentRentalID)

            Dim rs As OleDbDataReader = .ExecuteReader()
            While rs.Read
                RentalDayCount = rs("Noofdays")
            End While
        End With
    End If
```

Earlier when a user creates a new rental it sets that rental id to the current rental id im now trying to select from the rental table that rental and get the Noofdays value. Im trying to assign that value to 'Rentaldaycount'

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: What's the question here?  Is the query not returning expected results, or are you having trouble using the results in your VB?

Comment: 'Rentaldaycount' comes from the 'Noofdays' value within the table. For example if Noofdays = 3 Rentaldaycount = 3. But atm its just 0

Comment: Not quite sure i understand your question, but your SQL isn't returning anything called `Noofdays`.  You need to add it to your select list: "`Select Noofdays, Tbl_Rental.RentalID from Tbl_Rental....`"  Though I'm surprised this code in it's current form isn't throwing an exception

Comment: Ive updated my original code to include the noofdays but i still get the same problem

Comment: Does a different value exist in your database?

Comment: No ive checked the value is three. Could it have something to do with my parameters

Answer (score 0):

Use `Option Strict On` and also `Option Explicit`. Spend a little time fixing up the errors that are exposed.

I think your problem lies in these two lines.

```
        .CommandText = "Select Tbl_Rental.RentalID, Tbl_Rental.Noofdays from Tbl_Rental Where RentalID = @CurrentrentalID"
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RentalID", CurrentRentalID)
```

You use `"@RentalID"` on the second line, but `@CurrentrentalID` on the first line.

Also, we cannot see where `CurrentRentalID` or `cn` is set. Your snippet implies that start of the `Sub` directly before these lines, so they could be empty, null or anything else that does not make sense.

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean what exactly should i change about them two lines?

Comment: @haz14 should `@RentalID` be `@CurrentrentalID`?

Comment: Yeah when i create a rental initially it sets the current rental id to the rental id created so when i select from the database now it selects the rental id that = the current rental id

Comment: @haz14: Ok - blind spot here. Check that your parameter names match.

Comment: Ah realised i spelt the CurrentRentalID's differently but that still doesnt solve my problem

Comment: Did you do the first step (`Option Strict On`, `Option Explicit`)?

Comment: No where abouts in the settings are they?

Comment: The settings are here Tools Menu -> Options (all the way at the bottom) -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults  It would be best to set this form the start page so it would be automatic for all new projects.